# grabbing data from a ASP.NET webForm

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I'm fairly new to web development and never before did i do any screen-scraping nor web-crawling, but yesterday a friend of mine asked me if i would be able to grab some data from [this](http://extranet.net4gas.cz/capacity_ee.aspx) website, which is not mine, nor his, but the data is publicly available even for download.
The problem with the data is, it's available only as one file per one date or company, rather than one file for multiple dates or companies, which involves a lot of tedious 'clicking trough' the calendar and so he thought it would be nice if i would be able to create some app that could grab all the data with one click and output it in one single file or something similar..

The website uses aspx webFrom with __doPostBack to retrieve the data for different dates, even the links to download the data in XSL aren't the usual "href=…" links, they are, i assume, references for some asp script…

To be honest the only thing i tried was PHP cURL which didn't work, but since i tried cURL for the first time, i don't even know if it didn't work because it is not possible with cURL, or just because i don't know how to work with it.
I am only somewhat proficient in PHP and JavaScript, but not in ASP, though i would't mind learning something new.

So my question is..
Is it at all possible to grab the data from a website like this? and if it is, would you be so kind as to give me some hints on how to approach this kind of problem?

the website, again, is here  http://extranet.net4gas.cz/capacity_ee.aspx

Thanks

Comment: It's possible in php but it's much easier with python perl or ruby mechanize. Probably easiest is to use selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has a nice WebClient class to do the job:

```
// Create web client.
WebClient client = new WebClient();

// Download string.
string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.microsoft.com/");
```

once you have the page html in a string you use regular expressions to scrape the content you are looking for. 
here is a very basic regular expression to give a hint:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
Match match = regex.Match("hello here 10 values");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Marosko, as you said the data on website is open for public, so for sure you can scrape data out of it. Now, it is to decrease the manual click through dates and scraping data out of it. I personally don't have much idea about how Curl will work but I am sure it will involve a lot of coding. I would rather suggest you to automate the entire process using some automation tool, like a software application. Try Automation Anywhere, I bought it few months back for some data extraction purpose and it worked very well. It is automated and you can check the [screen scraping](http://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/screenScrape.htm) capabilities it shows. Its my favorite  :)

Charles

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your suggestion, but i would rather try and do it myself as i'm on stackoverflow to learn some code.